# Pacxon in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Can any cocos2dx programmer help me out!!

I'm new to cocos2dx. My task is to create pac-xon game. 
I tried learning tutorials and did the initial placement of tiles and player.

But, I don't know about detecting collision between
1) player to enemy 
2) Tile to enemy.

So, anyone help me out to complete my task.

Here is what i have done now.

```
void GameScene::CollisionCheck()
 {
       targetRect = CCRectMake(tiles->getPosition().x - (tiles->getContentSize().width / 2), tiles->getPosition().y - (tiles->getContentSize().height / 2), tiles->getContentSize().width, tiles->getContentSize().height);
       playerRect = CCRectMake(mySprite->getPosition().x - (mySprite->getContentSize().width / 2), mySprite->getPosition().y - (mySprite->getContentSize().height / 2), mySprite->getContentSize().width, mySprite->getContentSize().height);
       enemyRect = CCRectMake(ET1->getPosition().x - (ET1->getContentSize().width / 2), ET1->getPosition().y - (ET1->getContentSize().height / 2), ET1->getContentSize().width, ET1->getContentSize().height);
       if (enemyRect.intersectsRect(targetRect))        // TargetRect = ET1, 
       {
           //CCLOG("Colliding");        // Enemy Touches Tiles reflect with some angel,       
       }

       if (playerRect.intersectsRect(enemyRect))
       {
           CCLOG("Game Over, Try Again!!!!");
       }
       if (playerRect.intersectsRect(targetRect))
       {
           // Player is top of Tile
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u could draw debug your playerRect and enemyRect by layerColor to know exactly does it have collidable.
and shouldn't forget that collidable check call consecutive on update funcion.
LayerColor you just pass width, height same size player/enemy but layerColor posittion should set like (player->getPositionX(or /Y)(0 - player->getContentSize().width(or height - width for x and height for y)/2)

Comment: I tried it. But, trace is printing continuously even without overlapping another tile